# How to create xml by php for soap for the below format

Tags: php

I am trying to integrate the shipment creation with some wsdl,I have to create the xml according to below xml

below is the format for the xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:pos="someurl">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<tem:Shipment_Creation>
<tem:SHIPINFO>
<!--Conditional:->
<pos:AppointmentDate> If Customer has given exact date for delivery</pos:AppointmentDate>
<!--Conditional:-->
<pos:AppointmentFromTime> From Time </pos:AppointmentFromTime>
<!--Conditional:-->
<pos:AppointmentToTime> To Time</pos:AppointmentToTime>
<!--Conditional:-->
<pos:CashOnDelivery> Amount of Cash on Delivery</pos:CashOnDelivery>
<!--Conditional:-->
<pos:CashOnDeliveryCurrency> Currency of cash on delivery</pos:CashOnDeliveryCurrency>
<pos:ClientInfo>
<!--Required:-->
<pos:CodeStation> Posta Account Station Code </pos:CodeStation>
<!--Required:-->
<pos:Password> Shipper Account Password</pos:Password>
<!--Required:-->
<pos:ShipperAccount> Shipper Account No.</pos:ShipperAccount>
<!--Required:-->
<pos:UserName> Shipper Account Username</pos:UserName>
</pos:ClientInfo>
<Conditional>
<pos:CodeCurrency> Currency Code</pos:CodeCurrency>
<!--Required:-->


</tem:Shipment_Creation>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

Comment: The manual is usually a good place to start looking in all case where you dont know something

Comment: okay thank you it would better if you have any sample code pls

Comment: Yea i bet, look in the manual its full of sample code, or google for a tutorial. Try to write something. If you cant get it workig as you want then come back with some code we can help to fix. **We dont write your code for you**

Comment: Ok i am writing myself.thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're a little lazy, use the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project (or online on https://providr.io). You won't wonder how to send your request and receive the response.